# How to trigger Azure Pipeline on every new push on any branch?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

My current implementation of Azure pipelines is to trigger only when a pull request is made to Develop branch. But, I want to run the pipeline on every new push on any branch. How to trigger that?

My current implementation of the Azure YAML file

```
trigger:
  - none
pr:
  - branches:
      include:
        - dev
```

and below that steps are configured.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You need to specify the trigger something like this. So for example, if there is anything pushed in `dev` branch a build will get triggered. [Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops)

```
trigger:
- dev
```

or to be more explicit:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - dev
    - another-branch
```

If no triggers are specified it will by default run for all branches. It can be explicitly defined as:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - '*'
```

Comment: Yes, that is for the specific branch, but I want to trigger a pipeline for any branch, where a new push is made

Comment: @artois - If you do not specify any specific, it will be triggered for all branches by default. Updated my answer.

Comment: Is that the correct indentation for the '- ' parts?

Comment: Also make sure that "Override the YAML continuous integration trigger from here" is unchecked under Pipeline > Triggers in Azure Devops.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, using Azure DevOps, I have this on my .yaml file:

```
trigger:
- '*'
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'
```

So, it gets **triggered** no matter to which branch I'm pushing to.
I hope it might help.

Note: the **pool** part is not relevant; I just added to give more context.

Answer (score 0):

If you have git and a repo created in your project, you can easily connect git to azure dev ops. So let's say you want to deploy every push you give to the master branch of your repo. You can connect your master branch to the azure DevOps so it deploys it automatically.

[This link will provide additional information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops-project/azure-devops-project-github)